# How can i prevent adding extra '\r ' and '\' in xml

Tags: xml, groovy

I want  to get xml  content  then  update  it    and   send it  back  to  it's  original  place,  but   evry  time  i  ru  my  code  it  seems  that  extra   characters  are added ('\r'  and '\n')  with  this  updated  data and  as  a  result  it  increases  file  size  ,  how  can i  remove  this  characters?
 **When  i try to  update  my  xml   at   first  time  it  changes  xml  tag  values  but  on  the  other  attempts it  neither  trows  exception nor updates  data,  is  it  because  that  this  '\n'  are changing  position  xml tag  values?  :** 
here is my  code:

```
def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(content)
            for(int i=0;i<value.size();i++) {
                date = value.get(i).substring(0, 10);
                 xml.Mr.ross.details.findAll( { p ->
                   p.runAs[0].text() == "true" &&  date.toString()== p.start[0].text();
                }).each({ p ->
                    p.start[0].value =addDays( p.start[0].text())
                    p.runAs[0].value ="true"
                })
            }



            def stringWriter = new StringWriter()
            new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(stringWriter)).print(xml)
            def newXml = stringWriter.toString()
            String trimmedString = newXml.replaceAll("(?m)^[ \t]*\r?\n", "");
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            InputStream stream1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(trimmedString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory1 = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dBuilder = dbFactory1.newDocumentBuilder();
            document = dBuilder.parse(stream1);
```

For example  xml    data  looks  like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><service>
  <Ms>
    <ross>
      <details>
        <start>
                                                                      2017-09-07                                              
        </start>
        <startDate>
                                                                      2017-02-02                                                
        </startDate>
        <endDate>
                                                                      2017-03-02                                                
        </endDate>
        <runAs>
                                                                      true                                                
        </runAs>
        <makeVersion>
                                                                      1                                                
        </makeVersion>
        <patch>
                                                                      this is  patch                                                
        </patch>
        <parameter>
                                                                      1                                                
        </parameter>
      </details>
    </ross>

  </Ms>
</service>
```

Comment: Whitespace doesn't matter does it?  It's the same data isn't it?  What issue are you seeing?

Comment: YES    IT'S    I  HAVE  UPDATED  XML    WHCIH I GET    AFTER  UPDATING IT

Comment: I have no idea what that means

Comment: yes  the  sentence  i've  written is  mindless  any  way  i mean that  i  have  added  xml  format   which i   get  after  updateing  operation